# Check for a key name when documents are differently nested / Only check nested property if "parent" exists

Tags: mongodb

Situation: Documents can be structured in two variants.

They can look like this (variant 1):

```
{ "content": {
    "formats": {
        "PNG": {...},
        "JPG": {...}
    }
}
```

or this (variant 2):

```
{ "content": {
    "PNG": {...},
    "JPG": {...}
}
```

I want to check whether a document contains e.g. `PNG` AND `JPG`, and I don't care whether they are within a `formats` property or not.

Before the second variant came into use, I used a simple:

```
{
    "content.formats.PNG": { $exists: true },
    "content.formats.JPG": { $exists: true }
}
```

and that worked beautifully.

But now I have to check for both variants. Something like this would be extremely handy:

```
{
    "content.?formats.PNG": { $exists: true },
    "content.?formats.JPG": { $exists: true }
}
```

But as far as I know, nothing like this (I'd call it "conditional nesting") exists.

I tried many workarounds, according to what I would do in pure JS, but they all of them fail with "TypeError: Cannot read property 'PNG' of undefined" -- which I presume is because `content.PNG` is accessed on a document that is variant 1 or `content.formats.PNG` on a document that is variant 2.

My latest try in circumnavigating such unallowed checks is:

```
{
    "$and": [
        { "$or": [
            {"content.PNG":{"$exists":true}},
            {"$and":[
                {"content.formats":{"$exists":true}},
                {"content.formats.PNG":{"$exists":true}}
            ]}
        ]},
        { "$or": [ /* the same for JPG */ ] }
    ]
}
```

But this doesn't work either.

How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.find({
    $or:[
        {
            "content.formats.PNG":{
                $exists:true
            }
        },
        {
            "content.PNG":{
                $exists:true
            }
        }   
    ],
    $or:[
        {
            "content.formats.JPG":{
                $exists:true
            }
        },
        {
            "content.JPG":{
                $exists:true
            }
        }   
    ]
}).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5d8847170b94f18bdc2a5c"),
    "content" : {
        "formats" : {
            "PNG" : {

            },
            "JPG" : {

            }
        }
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5d8847170b94f18bdc2a5d"),
    "content" : {
        "PNG" : {

        },
        "JPG" : {

        }
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5d8847170b94f18bdc2a5e"),
    "content" : {
        "PNG" : {

        },
        "JPEG" : {

        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5d8847170b94f18bdc2a5c"),
    "content" : {
        "formats" : {
            "PNG" : {

            },
            "JPG" : {

            }
        }
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5d8847170b94f18bdc2a5d"),
    "content" : {
        "PNG" : {

        },
        "JPG" : {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you have two properties that both have the name `$or`?

Comment: I took your query, wrapped the `$or`s in a `$and` and now everything works -- I'm pretty sure I tried it like this before, but thanks for getting me on the right track!

Comment: I'll accept your answer if you explain my question in the first comment -- those two `$or`s don't look right for me...

Comment: @Christallkeks Implicit ```AND``` operation is performed on the conditions. Please check the following link https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/query-documents. It says *Implicitly, a logical AND conjunction connects the clauses of a compound query so that the query selects the documents in the collection that match all the conditions.*